# How may I bind more than one path value to a label's text property?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Working in Visual Studio 2017 with C# on an Xamarin.Forms application, I have the following line within the creation of a `ListView`. Each item in the `ListView` is represented by one `Label`. I set each label's text property to that item's 'Number' value. It is working as when viewing the list while running.

```
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Number");
```

Along with the 'Number' value, each item in the list has a 'SecondNumber' value. How may I bind the 'Number' value, a hyphen, and the 'SecondNumber' value to the each label's text property?

I've tried the following without success:

```
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Number" + "-" + "SecondNumber");
```

Comment: Why are you binding to a value? You bind to properties that may change, not values. Just assign it `label.Text = "blah blah " + user.ShoeSize + " yada yada";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a combined value property to your object. This way, you can use it anywhere in your application.

```
public string Numbers{
    get {return this.Number + "-" + this.SecondNumber;}
}
```